# Elastic how to get rows by distinct column which is ordered by another column?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

In my elastic index I have 3 fields `userId`, `status`, `updatedAt` with other fields. Now I am trying to get all rows where `userId` and `status` is distinct. I can do this with [term aggregression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

But I have another requirement when multiple rows have the same `userId` and `status` i want to return the row with the smallest/earliest `updatedAt` field. That is while finding a distinct row, it should be ordered ascending by `updatedAt`.

How can i do this? Here is my attempt

```
GET user_history/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "info.status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_document": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort": {"updatedAt":"desc"}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```